# Authenticate username/password against IDP using Spring Security SAML

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I'm aware of how SAML is used for single sign-on (SSO). That is redirection to IDP from SP and getting the user's identity from the SAML response/assertion.

**My question is**: Can I use Spring Security SAML framework to define how to pass username and password as part of a SAML request XML for authentication? Note that I'm not talking about single sign on and just want authentication of username/password programmatically. I am receiving that username/password as part of a web service request (in the header) and the requirement is to validate that username/password against the IDP.

Does IDP provide any API or mechanism for authenticating the username/password that I receive as part of web service request?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAML 2.0 password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671767/saml-2-0-password-authentication)